# Do harmful floor tiles count towards the 100% completion of a floor?

Tags: persona-q

Some floors have trap floor tiles that have various effects. Every floor also has a chest that only opens when you have touched every floor tile at least once. Are you required to walk over these traps in order to get 100% completion of a floor or are they exempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they do. I checked by activating the treasure chest for that floor. It highlighted all of the tiles I have not touched, including all of the trap floor tiles.